How did Vladimir Arnold explain the difference in approaches between mathematicians and physicists?
In Vladimir Arnold's Problems for children from 5 to 15 he writes:

Note to problem 13. I tried to illustrate with this problem the difference in approaches to tasks by mathematicians and physicists, in my invited
paper in the journal “Physics – Uspekhi” for the 2000 Christmas jubilee. My
success surpassed by far what I intended: the editors, unlike preschoolers, on
whom I had been basing my experience, failed to solve the problem, and therefore altered it to match my 4mm answer as follows: instead of “from the first
page of volume 1 to the last page of volume 2” they typeset “from the last
page of volume 1 to the first page of volume 2”.
This true story is so implausible that I am including it here: the proof is
the editors’ version published by the journal.

I'm almost positive I once read (and enjoyed immensely) an English translation of that article.  But I can find no reference to it anywhere, not even to the Russian original.  Where is it?

Is it this one Arnold, Mathematics and physics: mother and daughter or sisters? (Physics – Uspekhi, 42 (1999) 1205–1217)?

@Conifold Yes, it is! If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

@Conifold PS Were you aware of that or did you somehow find it now? If so, how? I searched and searched.

I googled "Arnold Physics-Uspekhi mathematics physics", which brought up MathOverflow thread The Arnold – Serre debate (on the value of Bourbaki), where one of the answers linked this paper. I did not see it before, but its predecessor is discussed in Some references for Vladimir Arnold's thesis "Mathematics is a part of physics"?

I found it rather easily by including a few extra details of the original formulation and then googling (in Russian, verbatim: "физика успехи арнольд два тома пушкина"). Speculating that "Uspekhi" stood for UFN would probably help as well. Without a confident command of Russian I would probably still try to translate specific details, such as thicknesses of pages, and include them in the query. Worst case, it's fully localized, so now it's Shakespeare instead of Pushkin and inches instead of millimetres. Thankfully, that was not the case here.

Arnold's view that "mathematics is the part of physics where experiments are cheap" is rather unorthodox, although similar views came up in the controversy surrounding Jaffe-Quinn's 1993 essay that argued for the opposite, a strict separation between mathematics and theoretical physics, see Responses to Theoretical Mathematics... by A. Jaffe and F. Quinn. Arnold was not part of that dust up, but he wrote two polemical papers on the subject in the late 1990s. The first one, On teaching mathematics (Russian Mathematical Surveys, 53 (1998) 229–236), opened with the above quip:

"Mathematics is a part of physics. Physics is an experimental science, a part of natural science. Mathematics is the part of physics where experiments are cheap. The Jacobi identity (which forces the altitudes of a triangle to meet in a point) is an experimental fact in the same way as the fact that the earth is round (that is, homeomorphic to a ball). But it can be discovered with less expense. In the middle of the twentieth century an attempt was made to separate physics and mathematics.   The consequences turned out to be catastrophic. Whole generations of mathematicians grew up without knowing half of their science and, of course, in total ignorance of any other sciences. They first began teaching their ugly scholastic pseudo-mathematics to their students, then to schoolchildren (forgetting Hardy's warning that ugly mathematics has no permanent place under the sun). Since scholastic mathematics that is cut off from physics is fit neither for teaching
nor for application in any other science, the result was a universal hatred of mathematicians, both on the part of the poor schoolchildren (some of whom in the meantime became ministers) and of the users."

Arnold's opinions caused another dust up. The paper that the OP has in mind, Mathematics and physics: mother and daughter or sisters? (Physics – Uspekhi, 42 (1999) 1205–1217) was Arnold's response to it in defense of his views. It illustrated them with many examples of how mathematical conceptions are developed from applications, but his passion was still about (misguided, in his view) modern way of teaching mathematics that separates it from them, which he blames on Bourbaki:

"The statement that mathematics is the part of theoretical
physics in which experiments are very cheap immediately
invited numerous attacks from both sides, including even one
parody (written by A M Vershik)... I shall try to show that here the question is always of the same art — the art of mathematical description of the world...   For example, Hilbert explicitly announced that geometry is a part of physics because both the geometer and the physicist obtain their achievements in quite the same way. True, I am afraid that Hilbert just did not consider geometry as a part of mathematics because he said that for mathematics it is the same whether its 'points' are glasses of beer and all 'straight lines' are benches... It is pity that his followers, like Bourbaki, applied these
'harmless' ideas in the teaching of school mathematics
substituting juggling of logic symbols for the content rich
science of the structure of the world...   I underline that proofs in mathematics have always played
only a subservient role, somewhat like orthography or
calligraphy in poetry. Mathematics as well as physics is an
experimental science, and conscious addition of common
fractions 1/2 and 1/3 is a standard element common to all mankind culture. The attempts to break the habit of time and to stop any kind of progress is a natural, but very dangerous consequence of the universal bureaucratization and world struggle with culture."


Very interesting, thanks! Just a question about a detail, in case anyone knows. On p1, second column, Arnol'd mentions 'Saardam'. I've found out that this is an old name for the Dutch town of Zaandam, of windmill fame, where Peter the Great spent a short time to study shipbuilding, and, apparently, the mathematician Hendrik Lenstra was born — but that's still a long way from being 'among the greatest mathematical centers of Europe'. Is this just a mistake, a mistranslation, or an I missing something?
